# Are there plans to translate Heidegger's Black Notebooks into English?

Tags: continental-philosophy, heidegger

I am curious to see the extent to which he made a home for national socialism in his thinking. If only Derrida could have lived to have seen these notebooks, how his estimation of Heidegger might (or might not) have changed!

Comment: I believe there are translations or at least excerpts now available?

Comment: ["7 New Translated Excerpts..."](http://www.critical-theory.com/7-new-translated-excerpts-on-heideggers-anti-semitism/) on ct seems to be an instance; my sense is that given their recent release some formal and informal translations are already in progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An English translation of the first Notebook is forthcoming: Heidegger, M. (2016) Ponderings: Black notebooks 1931-1938. United States: Indiana University Press.

http://www.iupress.indiana.edu/product_info.php?products_id=807954

Answer (score 2):

Currently there isn't officially any anouncment about translation or release of the book in english. There are some little parts over the internet but they wont satisfy you surely. Altought there should be some translation going on somewhere and it will take time since the book wasn't released long ago. I can recommend you to check once in a while in amazon or other book store they often have an anouncment when something is going to be released. Good luck and hope you won't have to wait long.

Comment: I am shocked to see how expansive those volumes of heideggers gesamtausgabe are. They're like $120

Comment: @Kyle - they're meant for libraries and researchers -- they're generally printed on acid-free paper and hard-cover bound... also, they are printed in small runs. Ergo, they are not cheap.